# Trying to create a Node Server

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to create a local server with Node, but when I am starting it with `node server.js`(the name of the file) command, I got a problem with ***required*** function, could somebody help me? It tells me required is not defined. I am using node-v14.5.0. I am working on Angular course, which I took on Udemy, and the task of this lecture was to create a Node Server.

```
const http = required('http');
 
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end('Test');
});
 
// we want our server to listen to different app
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: It's `require`, not `required`. `const http = require('http');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace required('http') with require('http')